# Table is not creating

Tags: python, sqlite

I am making little project with sqlite3, but table is not creating.

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE students
             (rollno real, name text, class real)''')
            
        
conn.commit()
#close the connection
conn.close()
```

[see photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/877YA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a code error.

Please navigate to where you have the python file running/saved in the DB browser. File -> Open Database and select the `test.sqlite` file. You will then see something like this:

[image]

Code used:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE students
             (rollno real, name text, class real)''')
            
        
conn.commit()
#close the connection
conn.close()
```